# How can I get just the camera resolution in android studio (Camera2)

Tags: android

I need just the camera resolution of the device in pixels. I have tried this, but it doesnt show nothing on my app. I think I´m missing something

```
   @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            1);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    }
    @NonNull
    public Size getResolution(@NonNull final CameraManager cameraManager, @NonNull final String cameraId) throws CameraAccessException
    {
        CameraManager cameraManager1 = (CameraManager) getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE);

        final CameraCharacteristics  characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
        final StreamConfigurationMap map             = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);

        if (map == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to get configuration map.");

        }

        final Size[] choices = map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);
        final Size size = getResolution(cameraManager, cameraId);
        final float megapixels = (((size.getWidth() * size.getHeight()) / 1000.0f) / 1000.0f);
        final String caption = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%.1f", megapixels);
        textView.setText(caption);

        return size;
    }
```

}

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: I just want the cameras resolution on the app

Answer (score 0):

Try the next method. You need to pass an initialized instance of the [CameraManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager), and then camera lens identifier for which you wish to get the resolution from.

```
@NonNull
public Size getResolution(@NonNull final CameraManager cameraManager, @NonNull final String cameraId) throws CameraAccessException
{
    final CameraCharacteristics  characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
    final StreamConfigurationMap map             = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);

    if (map == null)
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to get configuration map.");
    }

    final Size[] choices = map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);

    Arrays.sort(choices, Collections.reverseOrder(new Comparator<Size>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(@NonNull final Size lhs, @NonNull final Size rhs)
        {
            // Cast to ensure the multiplications won't overflow
            return Long.signum((lhs.getWidth() * (long)lhs.getHeight()) - (rhs.getWidth() * (long)rhs.getHeight()));
        }
    }));

    return choices[0];
}
```

The method will return the resolution size. If you need to display it you have many options. For example if you need to display in a TextView the Width and Height in the format such as for example 1280x720 then you can do as next:

```
final Size size = getResolution(cameraManager, stringId);
yourTextView.setText(size.toString());
```

If instead, you need to show it in megapixels then you can do as next:

```
final Size size = getResolution(cameraManager, stringId);
final float megapixels = (((size.getWidth() * size.getHeight()) / 1000.0f) / 1000.0f);
final String caption = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%.1f", megapixels);
yourTextView.setText(caption);
```

Comment: See at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: If it doesn't open, it will be a different unrelated error, did you ask for the camera permissions? without the permissions is not possible to get any camera information. Post your log error.

Comment: I´m using this permissions <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full"></uses-feature>

Comment: Besides having the permissions in the manifest, you still need to perform the API request to get the permissions granted. Having the permissions in the manifest does nothing if you don't get them granted via the permissions system dialog. Some permissions don't need granting, but the camera permission needs it. See the next link in the section "Request the permissions you need": https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: I did that already, but now on the app it doesn´t show any information

Comment: could you post the traces from your logcat? These should show the errors

Comment: 2020-01-24 12:04:01.164 28975-28975/? E/e.myapplicatio: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000