# how to find camera megapixels in android studio camera2

Tags: java, android

I need to get the device camera megapixels, but I don´t know how to do it. I want to use textView so I can show it on the app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get just the camera resolution in android studio (Camera2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59844000/how-can-i-get-just-the-camera-resolution-in-android-studio-camera2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the megapixel with this piece of code:

```
    public void getCamerasMegaPixel() {
        Camera camera = Camera.open(0); // For Back Camera
        android.hardware.Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
        List supportedPictureSizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
        Camera.Size result = null;

        ArrayList<Integer> widthList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> heightList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < supportedPictureSizes.size(); i++) {
            result = (Camera.Size) supportedPictureSizes.get(i);
            widthList.add(result.width);
            heightList.add(result.height);
        }
        if (widthList.size() != 0 && heightList.size() != 0) {
            System.out.println("Back Megapixel :" + calculateMegaPixel(widthList, heightList));
        }
        camera.release();

        widthList.clear();
        heightList.clear();

        camera = Camera.open(1);        //  For Front Camera
        android.hardware.Camera.Parameters params1 = camera.getParameters();
        List sizes1 = params1.getSupportedPictureSizes();
        Camera.Size result1 = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < sizes1.size(); i++) {
            result1 = (Camera.Size) sizes1.get(i);
            widthList.add(result1.width);
            heightList.add(result1.height);
        }
        if (widthList.size() != 0 && heightList.size() != 0) {
            System.out.println("FRONT Megapixel :" + calculateMegaPixel(widthList, heightList));
        }

        camera.release();
    }

    public float calculateMegaPixel(List<Integer> widthList, List<Integer> heightList) {
        return ((Collections.max(widthList)) * (Collections.max(heightList))) / 1024000;
    }
```

update if you want to use camera2 api, you can use here:

```
public String getCamerasMegaPixel() throws CameraAccessException {
    String output = "";
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

    String[] cameraIds = manager.getCameraIdList();
    CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraIds[0]);
    output = "back camera mega pixel: " +  calculateMegaPixel(characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_PIXEL_ARRAY_SIZE).getWidth(),
            characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_PIXEL_ARRAY_SIZE).getHeight()) + "\n";

    characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraIds[1]);
    output +=  "front camera mega pixel: " + calculateMegaPixel(characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_PIXEL_ARRAY_SIZE).getWidth(),characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_PIXEL_ARRAY_SIZE).getHeight()) + "\n";
    return output;
}
public int calculateMegaPixel(float width, float height) {
    return  Math.round((width * height) / 1024000);
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206480/discussion-on-answer-by-saeed-foroughi-how-to-find-camera-megapixels-in-android).